# Android Helper class -> null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, helper

i would like to ask:

I have in my AppHelper class following method which check availability of internet connection.

```
public boolean checkInternetConnection(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "Internet Connection Not Present");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Im trying to get Boolean value by using:

```
// check internet connection and availability
        Boolean isConnectionAvailable = appHelper.checkInternetConnection(getBaseContext());
```

But unfortunately i get always null pointer exception. Is it matter of passed application context? And how should i solve that issue?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `getBaseContext()` is almost always the wrong context to use. But do post complete stacktrace from logcat and show where you initialize `appHelper`.

Comment: as previous said and also, standard question: do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in your manifest?

Comment: (Cannot be about the context since you're not using the passed-in context for anything.)

Comment: you dont even say in what line you have null pointer exception. it is the first thing that you have to look at. i wonder how people can program without reading the logs or using the debug tools...

Comment: @Jiri must have missed that when pasting here. I bet it should be `ctx.getSystemService`.

Comment: I think too, that context is not used in method. I tried passed it without context in params but still same problem. 

Yes, manifest has following:
android.permission.INTERNET"/>
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: @FD_, not really, if the method is inside an Activity or any other class that has valid context.

Comment: From the title: `... Helper Class`, which I expected to be derived from Object.

Comment: My helper is extended from Activity:
public class AppHelper extends Activity

Comment: @Jiri Then that Activity is most likely not even running. Are you trying to call this helper from another Activity (your "main" activity)? Make sure the helper activity is first started, fire it off with an intent (I'd put the test connection method in a background service instead though).

Comment: @Jiri, I'd recommend to copy Logcat here to save everyone's time and ofcourse yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say that AppHelper class is a seperate Activity that is never properly started with an intent.

If this is so, I would instead implement AppHelper as a Service instead of an Activity, as the method "checkInternetConnection" is better suited for this type of task.

Weather or not the service runs in its own process or not I suppose would depend on the particular problem at hand.